# In Snowflake what is the difference between SELECT TOP and SELECT ... LIMIT

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Is there a difference between `SELECT TOP n col` and `SELECT col ...LIMIT n`

Both seem to return the same results. For example:

```
SELECT TOP 5 C_ACCTBAL FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."CUSTOMER";

SELECT C_ACCTBAL FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."CUSTOMER" LIMIT 5;
```

both return:

```
C_ACCTBAL
711.56
121.65
7498.12
2866.83
794.47
```

Answer (score 5):

According to documentation there is no difference

> TOP  and LIMIT  are equivalent.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/constructs/top_n.html

--- EDIT ---

BUT just as @Robert Long said, LIMIT supports OFFSET but TOP does not.

Comment: `LIMIT` supports the use of OFFSET, whereas `TOP` doesn't, as far as I know.

Comment: That well may be. I just read documentation. Just for pure interest, I will test.

Answer (score 3):

With the basic usage pattern in the OP, there is no difference.

However, `LIMIT` also supports the use of OFFSET, which will skip rows first.

So, we might have:

```sql
SELECT TOP 5 C_ACCTBAL FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."CUSTOMER";
```

which returns

```
C_ACCTBAL
711.56
121.65
7498.12
2866.83
794.47
```

..as in the OP, but:

```
SELECT C_ACCTBAL FROM "SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA"."TPCH_SF1"."CUSTOMER" LIMIT 2 OFFSET 3;
```

will return

```
C_ACCTBAL
2866.83
794.47
```